# Keep form on desktop at all times (No Win+D effects)

Tags: c#, forms, winapi

I'm working on a project in which I need a form to stay on the desktop at all times. This would mean that it should still be showing even if a user clicks Win+D to hide/show desktop.

If anyone uses Rainmeter, they will know how meters stay on the desktop despite clicking on the show desktop key.

I really don't mind how to do it, as long as it works. I've looked through hundreds of examples but half of them don't work..

Maybe someone could help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx

Comment: Is Rainmeter a desktop gadget?

Comment: Ritch - Yes it is. The reason why I'm not using RM is because it's not flexible enough for what I wanna do. So a custom app is the best option. However now I'm faced with a stupid positioning issue.. :(

Comment: @Capt.Morgan - Why not write another desktop gadget then?

Answer (score 2):

I fired up C# and created a Windows Forms application. I set the forms' `TopMost` property to `True`, and its `MinimizeBox` property to `False`.

When I run the app, the Window is always on top, even if I use Win+D or click Show Desktop.

I got the idea from here: [What is the difference between Minimize All and Show Desktop?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/27/143042.aspx)

Comment: Can always count on Raymond Chen when you're wondering about Windows API. :)

Comment: Given the mention of Rainmeter, he surely wants bottom-most.

Comment: Hans is right, Ove. Your answer would be ideal, however I want my form to be coverable by other windows/programs, but so that It would never cover anything, so yeah, bottom most but still ignoring the Win+D

Comment: @Capt.Morgan See Ove's [original link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx). What you're asking for is an arms race and is what "show desktop" was explicitly written to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something to stay on the desktop, you should put it on the desktop. Look at using [Windows Gadgets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd834142.aspx) which can do what you want.

Comment: The whole point of me doing it in c# is so I would not need to use windows gadgets. I don't want the app to be a windows gadget. I know it's the easy solution, but not one I am willing to go for.