# C# bring to front when WIN + D is pressed

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, desktop

When I go to my desktop using Win + D I want that my C# Winforms application is getting in front.

How can I make that?

Comment: The whole point of Win + D is to hide all the open applications and show the desktop. Circumventing that to force your application to the front would likely cause users annoyance.

Comment: In my case the desktop is not needed.

Comment: Try this: in the form:s lostfocus event, use `this.Show()`

Comment: I am using winforms and cant find any lostfocus event

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep form on desktop at all times (No Win+D effects)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261429/keep-form-on-desktop-at-all-times-no-wind-effects)

Comment: But this question has no working answer too

Answer (score -4):

I solved the problem.

I just killed all explorer tasks when starting and brought back when closing.